# Library for parsing URI from String with fragment before query

Tags: java, uri

Is there a library that would parse fragment and query from String to URI even if the string has the fragment and query in a wrong order?

```
import java.net.URI;

public class UriTest {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        String validUriString = "http://localhost:4200/?name=value#/fragment";
        String invalidUriString = "http://localhost:4200/#/fragment?name=value";

        URI validUri = URI.create(validUriString);
        URI invalidUri = URI.create(invalidUriString);

        System.out.println("OK:     "+validUri.getFragment());
        System.out.println("OK:     "+validUri.getQuery()+"\n");
        System.out.println("NOT OK: "+invalidUri.getFragment());
        System.out.println("NOT OK: "+invalidUri.getQuery());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
OK:     /fragment
OK:     name=value

NOT OK: /fragment?name=value
NOT OK: null
```

Would be nice to get the same result in both cases.

Comment: you just have to take the fragment, split on `?`, then split on each `=` to get key-value-pairs and then urlDecode them

Answer (score 0):

No guarantees if this will work for all URLs, but you can try to check if the url is broken and fix it like this:

```
...

public static String fixUrl(String url) {

    int fragmentIndex = url.indexOf("#");
    int queryIndex = url.indexOf("?");

    if(fragmentIndex < queryIndex && fragmentIndex > -1) 
        return url.substring(0,fragmentIndex) + url.substring(queryIndex) + url.substring(fragmentIndex, queryIndex);
    else 
        return url;

}

public static void main (String[] args) {

    String validUriString = "http://localhost:4200/?name=value#/fragment";
    String invalidUriString = "http://localhost:4200/#/fragment?name=value";


    URI validUri = URI.create(fixUrl(validUriString));
    URI invalidUri = URI.create(fixUrl(invalidUriString));

    System.out.println("OK:     "+validUri.getFragment());
    System.out.println("OK:     "+validUri.getQuery()+"\n");
    System.out.println("OK: "+invalidUri.getFragment());
    System.out.println("OK: "+invalidUri.getQuery());

}
```

Comment: thanks, but I was hoping for a library method that would deal with this. Seems like the kind of problem that endlessly many developers had to have before. (I will modify the title to make this clear)

Comment: According to this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier#Generic_syntax the URL that isn't working does not follow the specs. Meaning that no library will implement this and the only solution is doing it yourself.